# Probability puzzle: probability distribution of sum of Bernoulli times Rademacher trials

Tags: probability

I have a random variable $X=\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$ where $X_i$'s are independently and identically distributed as Bernoulli$(1/k^2)\cdot$Rademacher($1/2$). What is the probability distribution of X -  is there a (simple?) expression for $P(X=q)$? There are a combinatorially lot of ways by which X can be q, so a brute force strategy seems difficult but I am wondering perhaps there is an elegant  way yo calculate it.

Comment: Take a look at [Motzkin paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number#Combinatorial_interpretations).

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_i:=X_i+1$ and $Y:=\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i$ s.t. $Y=X+k$ and $Y\ge 0$. The probability generating function of $Y_i$ is given by
$$
G_{Y_i}(z)=\mathsf{E}z^{Y_i}=\frac{1}{2k^2}(z^2+1)+\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)z,
$$
and, therefore, $G_Y(z)=\left[G_{Y_i}(z)\right]^k$. Then the required probabilities can be found as follows:
$$
\mathsf{P}(X=x)=\mathsf{P}(Y=x+k)=\frac{G_Y^{(x+k)}(0)}{(x+k)!}, \quad x=-k,\ldots,k.
$$
For